# Bending hair around origin by applying simulated force

Tags: 3d, simulation, physics

I have a single hair, several millimeters to several centimeters in length, represented by several points (segments) p0, p1, p2, … on a straight line in 3D space. p0 is the origin and is immovable, all other points should be affected by gravity (and other forces), which means they should bend around p0 depending on how much force is applied and from which direction, how far away they are from p0 and how strong the hair is.

I don't need perfect physical accuracy, so the hair can be considered to have zero width and volume and mass can be ignored as well. What would be a fast, sufficiently accurate (for rendering purposes) algorithm for calculating the new points p1, p2, … after applying the force?

Comment: I just realized I could probably use inverse kinematics for this, but maybe there are other, faster solutions?

Comment: I can not find the English therm for chain/rope physics the closest I found is this [caternary](https://mae.ufl.edu/~uhk/HANGING-ROPE.pdf) ... there are set of equations for ropes chains (one or 2 fixed points + force field + external force) which exactly describe your problem... you need to look for stress and deformation analysis topics from mechanical engineering. (or civic) this [5.4 TIAŽOVÉ PARABOLICKÉ REŤAZOVKY](http://uamt.fei.stuba.sk/vyucbove_materialy/mechanika/mechanika/frames52.html) is what I have in mind (but its in Slovak) so try to find something similar in your language...